# Rails 4: Active Record Validation error on: create

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

If I have some before create action like:

```
before_create :generate_token
private
def generate_token
  self.auth_token = loop do
    random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
    break random_token unless self.class.exists?(auth_token: random_token)
  end
end
```

When writing validations I find `validates :auth_token, presence: true, on: :create` fails.
However, `validates :auth_token, presence: true, on: :after_create` works.

Why is this?

ref. [Active Record Callback Order](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) and [Active Record Validations :on](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on)

**edit:** Curiously, `on: :before_create` passes validation, `on: :create` fails, and `on: after_create` succeeds. This is puzzling, could some please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs you linked, to:

```
(1) before_validation

(-) validate  <======== This runs before before_create callbacks are run

(2) after_validation

(3) before_save

(4) before_create
```

I would consider generate the token when the object is initialized.

```
after_initialized :generate_token
```

Comment: I linked to two docs, which are you referring to? The latter explains how ":on option lets you specify when the validation should happen". 

I appreciate your suggestion, unfortunately your response is confusing and unhelpful. You indicate the before_create state which I made no mention of in my OP.

Comment: Assuming I did, and inferring your pointy-arrow response translates to, "the validation fails because 'validate' occurs earlier in the life cycle of an Active Record object than 'before_create' " then your conclusion is still invalid:

Comment: Your logic above implies "validates [also] runs before create and after_create callbacks are run" (after_create happens after create, and both happen after validate in the life cycle). 

Therefore if before_create fails then after_create should fail and if (somehow) after_create did pass then create should pass as well.

Comment: However, as observed on: :after_create **passes** validation, on: :create does not. How can you explain this? You have not answered the question. Unless your answer was "read the docs you linked to".